# не могу добавить элемент в статическую коллекцию

Tags: java

пишу код где с одной статической коллекцией работают разные методы.
Начал писать и тут мне стали вылетать NullPointerException , сначала думал, что сам где то накосячил потом на всякий в чистом проекте проверил.
Создается класс, у класса создается поле типа List list ; , далее в методе мейн пишу
list.add("111");
и получаю NullPointerException.
Почему?
поле же статическое для всего класса. Походу забыл джаву, прошу помощи.
Использую jdks\azul-11.0.14.1\bin\java.exe

Вопрос:
Как добавлять элементы в статическую коллекцию?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MiniDuckSimulator {

    static List<String> point;


    public static void main(String[] args) {





        point.add("111");
        System.out.println(point);



    }
}
```

Comment: Вы объявили коллекцию, но не инициализировали ее. Поэтому она и `Null`. Попробуйте `List<String> point = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: У Вас только поле, в которое можно записать ссылку на коллекцию. А самой коллекции нет:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно ее проинициализировать перед добавлением элементов: Код ниже

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MiniDuckSimulator {
    static List<String> point = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        point.add("111");
        System.out.println(point);


    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сам себя запутал, что уже забыл про инициализацию)))) А я уже в панике сижу , типа в смысле, как так то)))